Any limitations on the SQL server name length for JDE?
-- a question for any DBAs that support JDE databases. (JDE being the name of an application, also known as JD Edwards).
I'm being told by our support provider for JDE that it has a 30-character length limitation on the name of the SQL Server that hosts the JDE database. Because we're migrating them to Azure Managed Instances with Failover Groups, the length of our new server names are well over 30 characters (due to the .database.windows.net suffix), and there's limited options for what we can do with DNS aliases. For our secondary (read-only) listener, we're at 36 characters.
The support provider is not too clear however if the 30 character limitation is on the server name, or the name of the ODBC DSN that references the SQL Server. I suspect it's just the ODBC DSN name, in which case it's not a problem for us at all, because we can call it MickeyMouse for all I care. :)
Can any DBA confirm one way or the other?

Sounds like an application limitation, not a database problem, no? Sounds like a question that the support provider needs to answer more clearly else a new provider may be needed. Also perhaps something you can test?

which version of JDE ?

It's JDE version 9.20.
